# Intellisense is not working after run the Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, intellisense

I am using following configurations & tools for Flutter:

1. Dart: v201.9317
2. Flutter: v52.1.1
3. Android Studio 4.1.1
4. Intellij Idea 2020.3

Following steps I have followed:

- Completely uninstall and re-install both the android studio and intellij idea.
- uninstalled both dart and flutter plugin and re-installed it.
- Invalidate cache and restart both android studio and intellij idea

The actual issue is when I open the Flutter project the intellisense is working perfectly but after I run the project in the emulator the suggestions are not coming. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is not working, show screenshots/screencast and describe the expected/actual result.

Comment: And have you just restarted the analysis server on demand?  I don't know how AS does it, but in VSC, it's a simple command.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I dont know about the dart analysis server to be very honest. but why it is so?